# Bounds for the quadratic form of inverse block matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inverse, block-matrices, matrix-norms

Consider the PSD symmetric invertible $k\times k$ block matrix
$$M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A\in R^{k_1\times k_1}$, $B\in R^{k_1\times k_2}$ ($C=B^T$), $D\in R^{k_2\times k_2}$, $A,B$ are PSD and symmetric.

Let $x\neq 0$ is a $k$-dimensional vector. I would like to find bounds (lower/upper) for some norm of the quadratic form
$W=x^T M x$ in terms of the blocks. Something like (this might not be the case):
$$
||W||\leq f(||A||,||B||,||C||,||D||,x),
$$
where $f$ is some function of the blocks and vector $x$.

I have tried to use the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, it gives bounds for the norm of $W$, but not considering the blocks, I was wondering if you could adapt it for the blocks structure of $M$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure that you want $\|A\|$? Already in the $1$-by-$1$ case, we have that $\|x^TA^{-1}x\|\le \lambda_{min}(A)^{-1}\|x\|^2$, while $\|x^TA^{-1}x\|$ is not bounded by any function of $f(\|A\|,x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to write the norm of $M^{-1}$ in terms of the norms of the blocks, an inequality also could be used.

Comment: I'm saying that at the very least you would want to use $\|A^{-1}\|$ instead, which is not a function of $\|A\|$. In general, your desired inequality cannot hold for the same type of reason.

Comment: I see, the inverse makes things worse. If we forget the inverse for now,  is there a way to write $||x^T M x||$ in terms of the blocks?

Comment: I have edited it, considering the matrix $M$ instead of $M^{-1}$, which might be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy–Schwarz, the Frobenius norm, and $y=Mx,\;$ one obtains
$$\eqalign{
x^Ty
 &\le \|x\|\cdot\|y\| \\&= \|x\|\cdot\|Mx\| \\
 &\le \|x\|\cdot\|M\|\cdot\|x\| \\
 &\le \|x\|^2\cdot\|M\| \\
 &= \|x\|^2\;\Big(\|M\|^2\Big)^{1/2} \\
 &=   \|x\|^2\;\Big(\|A\|^2 + 2\|B\|^2 + \|D\|^2\Big)^{1/2} \\
}$$
The Frobenius norm is crucial for utilizing the block structure of $M$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you do the step $||M||^2=\Big(\|A\|^2 + 2\|B\|^2 + \|C\|^2\Big)$. Also, if we replace $M$ with $M^{-1}$, would we still have a nice expression?

Comment: Of course. If $M^{-1}$ exists, then [you can write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) it as a block matrix, too. The step you're asking about only works for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: why does not the $D$ block appear in the expression? Isn't $\|M^{-1}\|=\|M\|^{-1}$? Any hint how to obtain a lower bound? thanks.

Comment: Oops! You're right, the $C$ should be a $D$. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Hi Greg, can you tell me a reference about the property above on the frobenius norm? Also, any lower bound could be found? Thanks.